# Firestore: How to add new document within a nested document?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my structure, I have a channel collection named `channel`:

```
 channel 
   channel1 : {
      name: 'Busy Guys'
      members: {
         user1 : {
            name: 'Allan',
            photo: 'a.photo.url'
         },
         user2 : {
            name: 'Pogi',
            photo: 'a.photo.url'
         }
      }   
   }
```

I want to add member to channel1, how can I achieve that. I have tried updating the `members` field but it overwrites the entire value.

```
channelReference.doc(channelId).update({
      'members': {'name': 'Arnold', 'photo' : 'http.photo.url'}
      ),
    })
```

Comment: So to understand better, do you need to add a new user under members?

Comment: You can change map to array and use `arrayUnion()` function to update array.

Comment: @AlexMamo, yes. The answer below worked.

Comment: @Mises, I can do that but it is easier to update a member info using map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dot notation. Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

```
channelReference.doc(channelId).update({
  'members.user3': {'name': 'Arnold', 'photo' : 'http.photo.url'}
  ),
})
```